# How to submit answers to a quizz using the REST API of Learndash LMS

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, learndash

A bit of context: I am developing a web application based on the wordpress LMS : Learndash.

I have been able to get a lot of data using the REST api, courses, lessons, quizzes, but I don't find the way to submit the user's answers of a quizz.
I have double read the documentations https://developers.learndash.com/rest-api/v1 and https://developers.learndash.com/rest-api/v2 but I don't find the endpoint that I need.
I am probably missing something.

Do you have any solution ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I'm afraid these are not existant and the solution must be coded by hand, hoping updates do not break everything.

Comment: I didn't find yet a solution

Comment: Unable to find api for this. Does anyone has done code for submitting answers to questions of a quiz?